# Error: Project 'start' could not be found in workspace

Tags: angular, npm

ng run start:en command is throw exceptions.

```
Project 'start' could not be found in workspace.
    Error: Project 'start' could not be found in workspace.
        at Workspace.getProject (...node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:93:19)
        at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js:117:41)
        at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:160:45)
        at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:201:35)
        at RunCommand.run node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js:14:25)
        at RunCommand.validateAndRun (node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:124:31)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        at Function.

    Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
            at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
            at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:ur": "ng serve --configuration=ed",
    "start:en": "ng serve --configuration=en",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ur": "ng build --configuration=ed",
    "build:en": "ng build --configuration=en",
       ...
}
```

I have tried all possible solution that i get from google stack overflow

1. delete `node_module` folder
2. `package-lock.json`
3. change npm version

Comment: You need to do `npm run start:en` not `ng run start:en`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the commands from `package.json`, you need to call them with `npm run`. `npm` will invoke the scripts inside `package.json`.

So, for you question to run `start:en` script in `package.json`, you will need to run

```sh
npm run start:en
```

Comment: I have Option "aot" is deprecated: Use the "aot" option in the browser builder instead. warning with this one.

Comment: what is your command? in package.json @MostafaSaadatnia

Comment: Yes there is in pakage.json